# is the function $f=\lambda A\in P(N).A\ \Delta B $ when B is a constant group a bijection?(ne-to-one correspondence)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

is the function $$f=\lambda A\in P(N).A\ \Delta B $$ when $B \subseteq N$ is a constant group a bijection?(ne-to-one correspondence)

Comment: f is incomprehensible..

Comment: why f is incomprehensible?

Comment: What does $\lambda$A mean?  What does P(A).A$\Delta$B mean?